# confusion with php's isset

Tags: php, arrays, isset

currently I'm cleaning up some code which creates a lot of php warnings.
I've got the following code:

```
if(isset($info[1])) {
        list($artist, $song) = explode(" - ", trim(strip_tags($info[1])));
        $fullname = trim(strip_tags($info[1]));
    }
```

So I only want to execute this block is the index 1 is set. But when executing the the script I still get "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ...." on this line.

So what would be the right way to check if there is a value at a specified index in my array?

EDIT:
I tried your solutions but it is still not working as I expect.
I've added some debug stuff which just increased my confusion:
I've added the following for testing:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($info);
echo "</pre>";
echo ".";
die();
```

and the result is:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 
)
.
Played @
[1] => Song Title
```

Right now I don't really know how to interprete the output... can you give me a hint!?

Comment: Maby `array_key_exists()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: Try `!empty($info)` assuming that is what you're testing? Pretty strange behaviour though.

Comment: still the same behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you might need to ensure that `$info` exists:

```
if (isset($info, $info[1]))
```

But my guess is that there's no ' - ' match in `$info[1]` after you trim it, and it's there that only one element is returned (and therefore, `list()` would complain that there's no 1 index).

Comment: I still can not really interpret my debug output which I added to my question but it seems you're right. I had to check the length after the explode call. Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to check if `$info` is really an array first:

```
if (is_array($info) && isset($info[1])) { 
    // ...
}
```

or if you only have numerical keys, you could use [count](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

```
if (count($info) > 1) { 
    // ...
}
```

or you could also use [array_key_exists](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
if (array_key_exists(1, $info)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this :

```
if( isset($info) && count($info) > 0 ) {
    if ( isset($info[1]) && !empty($info[1]) ) {
        ... your code goes here ...
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you :)